# Close Input Message Dialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Im new editating JOptionPane buttons so i have & JOptionPane.showInputDialog that needs to be closed when i click cancel button, the issue is that i've a Exception that shows Error creating the file if i click it, i just need the JOptionPane.showInputDialog closed when i click cancel (doing nothing), i can't assing a value like 2 that means close window.

here's the code that i've done.....

```
if(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Capture File Name","Mandatory Filed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE)) 
                    == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
```

Comment: Can you post like a liiitle bit more code, thanks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [JOptionPane.showInputDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) javadoc, this method returns a `String`:

```
public static String showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                     Object message,
                     String title,
                     int messageType)
```

If Cancel button is pressed it will return `null` so you get an exception trying to parse `null` as an `Integer`. You should do this check instead:

```
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Capture File Name","Mandatory Filed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
if(value == null) {
    // Cancel button was pressed, not value returned do whataver you need to do
}
```